# Multiple Monitors using separate "spaces", yet have screensaver stretch as if one space macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mojave

anyone know of a screensaver app that would allow me to have it viewed as as single "space" across multiple monitors, even when the multiple monitors are set up to be separate spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Even as one space you still get one screensaver on each, running independently. Not sure what you want is possible.

Comment: You mean like a mosaic display setup?

Comment: Yes, like when some people stretch a desktop image to cover several monitors, but its all the same image. My search has proved fruitless; its probably not possible.

Comment: As far as I am aware, any a single image spanning multiple monitors (at least on macOS) is a custom tiling creation from the user.  i.e. they "tile" the image into how many monitors they have, and set the 'tile' as that individual monitor's desktop background, resulting in a cohesive spread when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the current macOS. It would be necessary to write a screen saver that explicitly understands you want to draw across multiple screen surfaces.